# Review Audit - Questionable "Bad" Answer

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I failed the following audit, but want to ensure that I truly understand *why* this answer deserved to be marked as a "bad" answer.

[The answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/13212754)

I understand that it's not a stellar response, but is it really so poor that it belongs as an audit? To make it clear, I am not complaining about failing the audit - I simply want to learn exactly what makes this answer bad enough to flag so I don't fail future audits.

For reference, here is the question corresponding to the answer:

---

> **GCM: How to use same sender id for both android and ios app?**
>
> I know that it is possible (Android GCM: same sender id for more
> application) but I don't know how to make it happen.
>
> GCM is already working properly on our android app. Now we want to use
> it in our ios app too. But when I try to register ios app for gcm in
> google developer console, it always registers a new app and provides a
> new sender id.
>
> NOTE: No plan to use Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) yet.

---

And here is the answer in question:

> For Android and iOS you can use same senderID just go to Google
> Developer console and check for the same app ios and android.

The comment from the close voters was:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Which is false in my opinion. The answer **did** answer the question.

As I said, the answer isn't perfect, but it does appear to answer the question.

In fact, the question was asked previously and the accepted answer was:

> You can and should use the same sender_id and server key for Android and iOS given that they are the same application. Clients can receive/send messages from/to multiple servers (Developer console projects) but this is not necessary.
>
> Your server makes an XMPP connection with GCM and send and receive messages via GCM. A single XMPP server can send to both Android and iOS clients.

Which appears to be the same answer, albeit with slightly better wording. Is this simply a case of my standards being too low? I see "no action" as not deserving of an upvote, nor a downvote. To me, at least, this answer fit that category. It's not great, but it does answer the question.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you here. This post shouldn't have been flagged as NAA / VLQ and end up in the low quality review queue. Bad audit there.

Comment: I guess the original flag was probably due to its length. People often don't like short answers. Sometimes the audits aren't great but the right thing to do is it come to meta and check.

Comment: Please explain how that answer contains any actionable information. What I see is "Q: How do I do X? A: You can do X".

Comment: @AndrewMedico That is what down votes and delete votes are for.  NAA/VLQ flags should not be used to get rid bad/LQ answers. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: What's surprising is that all the reviewers [recommended deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12908285) in the LQP queue.

Comment: @AndrewMedico One can also answer with something was is neither related to the question or answers it. As long it answers _any_ question, it isn't suitable for NAA flag. I know this sounds bad, but this is what mods want.

Comment: @Ashish off topic, may I inquire why you voted to close this question as "off topic"? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332268

Comment: @Pekka웃 Um well... It looked to me like off-topic at the time I VTC'ed. I was just gonna leave for some work so had a brief look, and decided it was off-topic. Looks like I was wrong. Sorry for the trouble. I've voted to reopen