# Are users with low reputation supposed to be able to see a completed close vote review?

Tags: support

As I understand it, at 250 reputation you can [view close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) on your own questions, not other people's questions. Naturally, I found it interesting when I saw that I could view [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/11560) given on meta in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332268/#comment382507_332268).  I could see who completed the review:

[image: Who reviewed the close votes]

However, once I clicked back on the review tab on the top right hand corner, I got this familiar message:

[image: You need at least 3k reputation to review close votes]

Which makes me wonder, is it a bug in the system that allows me to see what happened when the review was completed?  Can I only do this when I have a link to the question's close vote review, or can I get to this another way (e.g. construct the url somehow)?

Comment: This is not a bug, everyone can view reviews, but only privileged users can perform a review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completed reviews are designed to be public, yes.  None of the information shown there is private.

Comment: So...can you view the reviews without the link?

Comment: @iRove Nobody can view a page without a link to that page.  That's how the internet works...

Comment: I mean, is there some place you can get a link to a specific question's completed review if you don't have the ability to see the close vote queue?  Or, does someone else have to give you the link by some means?  Can you create the link by knowing the question's id somehow?

Comment: You can see the reviews a user has completed from their profile.

Comment: So basically, in order for a low-rep user to see a completed close vote review, you have to know who close voted, go to the profile history under all actions, and find the link to the completed review.  There is no other way in a question to find the corresponding completed close vote review?  Wouldn't it be much better to have a direct link to the question's completed close vote review somewhere on the question's page?

Comment: @iRove To be fair, it's the same for every user.  Only moderators have a link to the reviews for a post from the post.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I didn't realize this.  Thank you for the clarification!  One _last_ question though.  Is there a reason that we don't have access to the corresponding review from a post?  It doesn't seem to make much sense to me.  I mean, have people created a feature request for this before?  Does it warrant a feature request?

Comment: @iRove The vast majority of people would never need to see it, it's virtually only a useful feature in meta discussions.  I'd use a lot for that reason, but I know I'm unusual in that regard.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Makes sense.  Thank you for following up with me on that. (◕‿◕)

Comment: @iRove You can see the completed reviews for a post in its timeline: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/332268/timeline#review_11560.

Comment: @davidism Wow!  I never knew about this feature!  Thank you for that :)